# В терминале Linux не отображается путь до текущей папки.

Tags: bash, linux

В linux, как и все, я часто хожу по папкам, туда и сюда, но текущее мое положение не отображается. Как сделать так, чтобы консоль мне показывала мое текущее местоположение.

Например:**-bash-3.2$** (Это всегда показывает)И даже если нахожусь в **/www/test/** все равно показывает **-bash-3.2$**А я хочу, чтобы отображалось: **-bash-3.2$:/www/test/**

Надеюсь все понятно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*man bash* на предмет PS1.

А так, в `.bashrc` пользователя напиши `PS1='\u@\h:\w\$'`, где `\w` — показывать рабочий каталог. И перелогинься после этого.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это именно то, что мне нужно.