# Как сделать что бы всегда показывалась текущая директория в терминале Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, терминал

Не показывает по умолчанию текущую директорию в терминале Ubuntu. Как узнавать не выполняя `pwd`?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/344494/178576

Answer (score 0):

В .bashrc пользователя пиши PS1='\u@\h:\w\$' где \w это показывает рабочий каталог. И перелогинся.