# Проблемы с терминалом

Tags: консоль, linux-mint

Что не так с терминалом, как исправить? Раньше указывался путь папки, в которой я нахожусь, сейчас такого нет.
[image: Что не так с терминалом, как исправить?]

Comment: Что именно вам не нравится? Промпт? Русские буквы?

Comment: Раньше указывался путь к папке в которой я нахужось, а сейчас этого нет.

Comment: @borrya как называется терминал? Покажите справка -> о приложении

Comment: Это определяется переменной PS1. У меня она задается в ~/.bashrc вот так `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$` / Возможно вы редактировали этот файл и попортили ее

Comment: так же стоит проверить в настройках галочку "запускать команду как оболочку входа": без нее `.bashrc` и прочие файлы настроек игнорируются

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В терминале Linux не отображается путь до текущей папки.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/344494/%d0%92-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-linux-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)